Were people allowed to smoke on TV back in the 1960s to 1970s?
In this movie, Late Night with the Devil (2023), where the timeline is set in the 1960s or 1970s, one of the guests is smoking a cigar when the program is on the air.

Were people allowed to smoke on TV back in the 1960s to 1970s?

In the 1950s, not only were people allowed to smoke on the air, they were thoroughly encouraged to do so. I Love Lucy was sponsored by Philip Morris. They smoked like chimneys on the show and then cut to adverts with Lucille Ball and Desi Arnaz smoking and talking about their favourite brands; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irtb4_Whios "You'll love them. They're so smooth and mild, and taste so good!"

People used to smoke everywhere, all the time It wouldn't even have occurred to them to restrict people from smoking on TV. The only exception would be places where a lit flame would actually be dangerous.

Lets take a radio and later TV-show like "Dragnet" - sponsored by "Fatima cigarettes - a mild cigarette" and "Chesterfield cigarettes - sound off for Chesterfield", where someone is smoking or asking for a cigarette, in every other episode.

I suspect that once cigarette ads became illegal on TV, risk-averse network lawyers weren't anxious to test whether the ban extended to content as well.

@A.I.Breveleri: There was a time when we were giving cigarettes and alcohol to children.  Wine was forbidden in French schools from 1956.

Was there any place people weren't allowed to smoke during the 60s to 70s? They smoked in maternity wards up until the 90s! https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1525741/

Heck, the show Endeavour (air dates 20212-2023) depicts like in Britain in the 60s - they smoke non-stop in that show. Ergo, people in TV shows produced today will smoke for accuracy in shows when it was common.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica, people stopped smoking on TV only recently, less than 15-25 years ago. Depending on the country, ofc.

Fred Flintstone used to smoke cigars in the middle of kids cartoons. Also he was in some out-and-out cigarette commercials.

You know, I'm pretty sure (USA) it is not literally illegal to have live personalities smoking currently on US broadcast TV.  For example, you could imagine some sort of interview show where the interviewer and the interviewee are smoking cigars.  For that matter, you can fairly easily imagine a 60 minutes (or whatever) interview where the interviewee is smoking.  It is illegal to run ads on broadcast TV for cigarettes, but I don't think there's literally a LAW that prevents one of the major broadcast networks for having a (say) interviewer or newscaster smoking.

@Fattie I was surprised by your comment, but after investigation, I think you're right. Smoking on TV isn't actually illegal. advertising is illegal, but not television. Many states have laws against smoking.... but almost all of them have an exemption for television/movies/shows/plays/etc.

I'm pretty sure the OP is asking about on live (such as news, etc) TV - correct?  It's still completely normal and legal (although less common) to see smoking in movies and streaming shows, created today. (Indeed, obviously, movies and shows created today often feature murder, drug use, sexual relations, etc etc - as well as drinking and smoking.)

@MooingDuck indeed. (I worked in TV and advertising for some years, but I was drunk the whole time, so you can maybe get better facts from someone else!)  I believe ads on billboards were still legal until later (I don't know what year - 2000 maybe)

Ironically, the reverse has occurred for the consumption of alcohol.  For a while, it was illegal to show anyone drinking anything that appeared to be alcohol on-screen, even if it wasn't real alcohol.  You could show people ordering a drink, you could show it being poured, you could show them raising the glass to their lips, but you'd always have to cut away before they took a sip.  Now you see people drinking all the time and nobody seems to object.

Yes
Famously, Edward R. Murrow, an american news broadcaster and commentator was often shown smoking on television.

An example video of a 1962 broadcast is found on youtube.



Indeed, many shows were sponsored by tobacco companies and smoking was even advertised as "healthy" by doctors.




Folks, no-one is disputing the fact that smoking is unhealthy. Comments are not the place for this discussion. Take it to chat please.

Another data point, as recently as the '90s: here is comedian Denis Leary on Late Night with David Letterman, 19 February 1993, smoking.




Leary was known (in fact renowned) for his consumption of cigarettes and refusal to work on set without them, despite the rules against it.

People used to smoke in aeroplanes, elevators, offices, and in cinemas. This post claims that smoking was allowed in cinemas in New York as late as 1988. I was surprised, though, to see a former nurse say:

I started working as a Respiratory Therapist in 1983. In those days we were smoking by the monitors at the nursing station in the ICU!

So I don't see why TV would have been an exception.

The question wasn't about smoking in general, it was about smoking on TV. Note that there are many things you can do in public in real life that you can't/couldn't do on US network telly, like saying the word "toilet"

@Valorum Smoking had no negative social status associated with it until the 80's. There's no reason why it would have been banned anywhere. Cigarette commercials were banned on TV in 1971, before that they were everywhere.

@Valorum exactly what Barmar already said. OPs question is only a question because of the societal context of how we now see and treat cigarettes/tobacco. In the 60s/70s context such a question would be somewhat absurd even because of course they would smoke on TV, why would they have such an unreasonable (at the time) discrepancy between lived reality and TV? Especially when there was NO motivation to do so and a lot of reasons to smoke on TV

Interestingly there was some stigma associated with smoking. In New Zealand, smokers were segregated into separate sections on trams, buses, and trains during the 50s through 70s. This cartoon (probably NSFW) suggests that the same thing happened in Australia.

@SimonCrase According to this timeline, Australian states were increasing provisions for non-smoking spaces on public transport between 1900 and 1920, with a ban on broadcast advertising coming in 1972-76.

@Hobbamok - TV doesn't always accurately represent reality.

@Valorum yes but reality-like formats usually stick closer to reality (ESPECIALLY in the mundane, everyday cultural norms/usual habits) unless there is a significant reason for divergence. You don't see Late Night Show hosts bow to each other as a greeting for every guest. No, they greet in the culturally normal ways because no thought is spent on that
